# Linux + "nVidia surround" + 3 monitors?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, nvidia-geforce

Is it possible to run 3 monitors on 1 nvidia card (600 series, 640/650/660/670) under linux/xorg with the closed source nvidia driver?

At the moment a have a 2 monitors on my linux system in a twinview configuration and i would like to add a third.

Comment: Have you already looked through the README? http://uk.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/304.43/README/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of my new 660ti i can now answer my own question:

Yes, you can use TwinView with 3 (maybe even 4) screens the same way you used it with 2 screens on older nvidia cards (testet with 3 screens: 2xDVI + 1xHDMI).

Comment: Yeah... it works. Thanks to your question and answer I bought a GTX 650 and got 4 screens up (2xDVI, VGA, HDMI) and running. :)

Answer (score 2):

As of September 22, 2012, the Nvidia site doesn't list the 650 as "supported" under Linux.   The 660ti is supported by driver version 304.43, released on August 27, 2012, so that's probably why the OP has joy:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-304.43-driver.html

With luck, the 650 will be in the next driver release.

Comment: Today (24. Sep) nvidia released 304.51 with support for 660 (non-ti) and 650

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, one card supports 4 Displays with 2D and 3 Displays with 3D.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you use (or have seen) such a setup or have you only read somewhere that it should work?

Comment: I actually went to the Nvidia website and read it on there, it's very nicely shown in the technical overview of the cards. You should try it out, just surf to www.nvidia.com and just look for your card and then click specs. It's incredible how much information vendors put on their website!

Comment: I know that the hardware does support 3 or 4 displays. What i don't know is if their linux driver supports it.
All the information i found on the nvidia side about "NVIDIA Surround" was about using their graphic cards with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will need to use Xinerama, don't think that twinview can deal with more than 2 screens.

I have never done this myself but i have read quite a few posts from people with up to 6 monitors (on linux systems). See [here](https://superuser.com/q/132290), for example.